# Laravel 5.6 - Using model functions in ModelFactory

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.6

I am working with `Laravel 5.6` and found myself a weird problem while extending the functionality of my project.

Right now i need to create two new models: `order` and `item`. It was quite easy to fill the items table with dummy data using `Faker` and Laravel Factories/Seeders. The biggest problem is while working with the `order` model.

This little fellow is related to a `company` with a foreign key named `company_id` and `user` with a foreign key named `seller_id`. The company field is okay, the trouble is behind my `seller_id`

This seller needs a `role` related to the company my factory will randomly pick for it because the user is not related to the company (directly) and i can't just  look for it with a `company_id`.

In order to get all the users "related" to my company, i've created the next function on my `Company` model:

```php
public function users()
{
    $roles = $this->roles;
    $users = [];
    foreach ($roles as $role) {
        foreach ($role->users as $user) {
            $user->makeHidden(['pivot']);
            array_push($users, $user);
        }
    }

    $users = array_unique_objects($users);
    return $users;
}
```

btw: I'm using `laravel-permissions`, a library made by Spatie.

What this functions does is get every `role` from a `company` and then it pushes it to an array of users.

This custom helper: `array_unique_objects` tracks any repeated user on my array and removes them.

That function works find because i've tested on a couple of controllers so i know there is no problem with it. Either way, my `OrderFactory.php` looks like this:

```php
<?php

use Faker\Generator as Faker;

use App\Models\User;
use App\Models\Company;

$factory->define(App\Models\Order::class, function (Faker $faker) {
    $company = Company::get()->random(1);
    $users = $company->users();
    $user = array_random($users);
    return [
        'company_id' => $company,
        'seller_id' => $user->id,
        'code' => strtoupper(str_random(10)),
        'description' => $faker->sentence($nbWords = rand(2, 4), $variableNbWords = true),
        'created_at' => $faker->dateTimeBetween($startDate = '-1 year', $endDate = 'now', $timezone = null)
    ];
});
```

But when i run the `php artisan db:seed` command, it throws the next error in console:

> BadMethodCallException  : Method Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection::users does not exist.
>
> at >/home/ironman/Documentos/Sandbox/Proventas/Backend/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Support/Traits/Macroable.php:99
>   95|      */
>   96|     public function __call($method, $parameters)
>   97|     {
>   98|         if (! static::hasMacro($method)) {
>    99|             throw new BadMethodCallException(sprintf(
>   100|                 'Method %s::%s does not exist.', static::class, $method
>   101|             ));
>   102|         }
>   103|
>
> Exception trace:
>
> 1   Illuminate\Support\Collection::__call("users", [])
>   /home/ironman/Documentos/Sandbox/Proventas/Backend/database/factories/OrderFactory.php:10
>
> 2   Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factory::{closure}(Object(Faker\Generator), [])
>   /home/ironman/Documentos/Sandbox/Proventas/Backend/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/FactoryBuilder.php:274
>
> Please use the argument -v to see more details.

Is there anything I can do to fix this problem? I know that using Laravel Relationships will fix my problem but the specifications of this project says that i have to keep things just as the are.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your call to

```
$company = Company::get()->random(1);
```

does not return a single company. It returns a Collection, which does not have a *users* dynamic function. Try

```
$company = Company::get()->random(1)->first();
```

Comment: You were right, that is exactly what it does. Thank bvery much!